# jQuery add style if class is added?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem when I'm adding a class to a div with jQuery: while doing so, I also need to add some styles to `<body>`.

I have something like this:

```
<body>
.....
<div="class-one"></div>
```

and I know how to add a class to `.class-one` with jQuery using `click` event handler, but at the same time I need `overflow: hidden` to be added to `<body>`!
My jQuery code is:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
    $(".class-one").toggleClass("active");
});
```

It is OK, but how can I add a style to `<body>` after toggling `.active` class on `.class-one`? I mean if `.class-one` gets ACTIVE, then `<body>` should get `overflow:hidden`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class-one");
elements[0].style.display="none";
```

U can use that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can give jQuery and css like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
     $(".class-one").toggleClass("active");
     $("body").toggleClass("overflow");
});

body.overflow{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` keyword. Here i have showed how to change the style of the element on click.

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
       $(".class-one").toggleClass("active");
       $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    });
```

Rather than click, i would like to suggest mouseover method

```
$( 'body' ).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
})
```

;

Comment: toggle means that if the class is there it will remove it, if the class is absent it will add it. Op want to add something only if the class is active. So with jquery you would have to use hasClass or $(".active"). Or use css for what it's intended. With "this" you will add it everytime unless you check with hasclass

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, when .button add class active then body overflow is hidden else overflow auto.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
     jQuery(".class-one").toggleClass("active");
     if (jQuery('.class-one').hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
     }else{
        jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag. If `.active` isn't present on `.class-one` initially, we can set that flag to `false` (otherwise, to `true`). Then just switch it back and forth (true/false) upon each click. If the flag is `true` - it means that the `.active` class has been added, so apply your styles to `body`:

```
var isActive = false;
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
   $(".class-one").toggleClass("active");
   isActive = isActive ? false : true;
   if(isActive) $('body').css("overflow", "hidden"); else $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
});
```